# Ubuntu taken total unallocated disk space in dual mode

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I've installed `window 7` with 2 partitions and kept nearly `100gb` unpartitioned to install `Ubuntu 12.04`. While installing `Ubuntu` it has not been asked "how much swap space should be allocate", it simply picked up total unpartitioned space. Is it normal behavior ?, I've observed that partition info will be asking while installing `Ubuntu as Primary OS` instead of dual boot.

And another thing is `Windows` partitions are appearing under `Ubuntu Devices` and able to mount `Windows` partitions. How its happening without any extra effort or without installing applications ? Hope it won't create a issues for both OS data ?

I'm new to dual boot usage, So thought to know information from here.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally Normal that Ubuntu takes all the unallocated space. Usually when clicking Install Alongside Windows, It configures it all for you.

The Answer To Your Second Question: Yes, Its Totally Normal and should not cause Any Issues.

For More Information About Dual Boot: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to just confirm the points.

Comment: In terms Of? How dualboot Works?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point.